# Show Online Users in sidePanel using codeigniter and ajax

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter

Side Panel Code:-

```
<div id="slide_panel">
    <div id="showusers"></div>
        <div id="holder">
            <div id="stick"><span>Chat</span></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Of Sidepanel:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var stick = $('#stick');
var panel = $('#slide_panel');
var left  = $('#stick').offset().left; 
var right = $('#stick').offset().right; 
    $("#stick").on('click',function(){
        $("#slide_panel").toggleClass("anim");
    });

});
</script>
```

Here Now When i click on chat button it show the side panel and in that I want display Online users For chat using ajax.
I want to display online users list In this DIV:-"`<div id="showusers"></div>`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("#stick").on('click',function(){
    $("#slide_panel").toggleClass("anim");
    // simplest
    $("#showusers").load('/your/controller/which/returns/userlist/');
    /*
    .. or ..
    $.get('/your_controller/',function(response){
        $("#showusers").html(response);
    });
    */
});
```

Comment: @KimJones If my answer solved Your problem, don't forget to mark it as "Answer". Thanks